# How can i use web speech api and agora.io simultaneously?

Tags: agora.io, webspeech-api

I am using Agora.io for a web application (web SDK). I would like to use the web speech api on top of streaming video and audio. The web speech api works as long as I do not have a stream running.

It looks like the Agora.io web SDK monopolize the microphone and kicks out the web speech api listeners.

Is there a way to use the microphone in different contexts simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to browser limitations. Web speech APIs do not give out a mediastream object or accept a mediastream. So WebRTC can't work in tandem with this.

You can try google speech-to-text API. It works well with mediastreams.